# SQL constraint for column

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

I have a column that is called NumberInStock. However, in the database I want to limit the values that can be entered into this column between 1 and 100. What Constraint would I use on the column and would would be the proper syntax of the SQL query? What I got so far is:

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
ALTER COLUMN NumberInStock
```

Now what do I put after that to put the constraint and what constraint would I use

I'm using MySQL that has a 1999 ANSI/ISO standard.

Comment: You have to tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Just added what DBMS I'm using to the post

Comment: MySQL does **not** support check constraints. Even though it will accept the SQL from the accepted question it will silently **ignore** it!

Comment: See this question at DBS.SE: **[check constraint does not work?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work)** where 2 options/workarounds are given, using either triggers or a foreign key to a reference table (the 2nd is suitable only in some cases).

Comment: domecraft check my answer.

Comment: Alright, I think i'm going to use a trigger to work around the constraint not working. I should have added that the reason I'm asking this is because the constraint wouldn't work for me. Appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this type of problem should be solved using a **CHECK constraint** as follows-

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory ADD CONSTRAINT chk1 CHECK(NumberInStock BETWEEN 1 AND 100);
```

This could have been done in **ORACLE** But **MySQL** has a **[BUG reported](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48599)** regarding the implementation of check constraint.

Hence u must implement two triggers i.e. one for **INSERT** and another for **UPDATE** on that table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that MySQL was acting weird but I realized it was because I was using queries meant for Oracle and I never realized the syntax would be that different for MySQL.

Comment: You can simply think of MySQL as a DBMS with reduced functionality of ORACLE. After all it is widely used in many enterprise application and both ORACLE and MySQL comes from ORACLE corp.

Answer (score 0):

Use Check constraint .

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME>
ADD CONSTRAINT <CONSTRAINT NAME> CHECK(<PREDICATE> OR/AND/NOT <PREDICATE> ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried looking it up online but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: In MySQL, `CHECK` constraints are parsed for syntax correctness and then **ignored**. No checking will be done on the values!